# View Table over Language/Client/Status Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I would like to simplify my data with a view table, `MainView` but am having a hard time figuring it out.

I have a `Fact` table that is specific to clients, language, and status. The ID in the `Fact` table comes from a `FactLink` table that just has an `FactLinkID` column. The `Status` table has an `Order` column that needs to be shown in the aggregate view instead of the `StatusID`. My `Main` table references the `Fact` table in multiple columns.

The end goal will be to be able to query the view table by the compound index of `LanguageID`, `StatusOrder`, `ClientID` more simply than I was before, grabbing the largest specified `StatusOrder` and the specified `ClientID` or `ClientID` 1. So, that is what I was hoping to simplify with the view table.

So,

**Main**

```
ID  | DescriptionID | DisclaimerID | Other
----+---------------+--------------+-------------
50  | 1             | 2            | Blah
55  | 4             | 3            | Blah Blah
```

**Fact**

```
FactID | LanguageID | StatusID | ClientID | Description
-------+------------+----------+----------+------------
1      | 1          | 1        | 1        | Some text
1      | 2          | 1        | 1        | Otro texto
1      | 1          | 3        | 2        | Modified text
2      | 1          | 1        | 1        | Disclaimer1
3      | 1          | 1        | 1        | Disclaimer2
4      | 1          | 1        | 1        | Some text 2
```

**FactLink**

```
ID
--
1
2
3
4
```

**Status**

```
ID | Order
---+------
1  | 10
2  | 100
3  | 20
```

**MainView**

```
MainID | StatusOrder | LanguageID | ClientID | Description   | Disclaimer  | Other
-------+-------------+------------+----------+---------------+-------------+------
50     | 10          | 1          | 1        | Some text     | Disclaimer1 | Blah
50     | 10          | 2          | 1        | Otro texto    | NULL        | Blah
50     | 20          | 1          | 2        | Modified text | NULL        | Blah
55     | 10          | 1          | 1        | Some text 2   | Disclaimer2 | Blah Blah
```

---

Here's how I implemented it with just a single column that references the `Fact` table:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.KeywordView
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.KeywordView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT t.KeywordID, f.ClientID, f.Description Keyword, f.LanguageID, s.[Order] StatusOrder
FROM dbo.Keyword t
JOIN dbo.Fact f
    ON f.FactLinkID = t.KeywordID
JOIN dbo.Status s
    ON f.StatusID = s.StatusID
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX KeywordIndex
    ON dbo.KeywordView (KeywordID, ClientID, LanguageID, StatusOrder)
```

---

My previous query queried for everything except for that `StatusOrder`. But adding in the `StatusOrder` seems to complicate things. Here's my previous query without the `StatusOrder`. When I created a view on a table with just a single `Fact` linked column it greatly simplified things, but extending that to two or more columns has proven difficult!

```
SELECT
  Main.ID,
  COALESCE(fDescription.Description, dfDescription.Description) Description,
  COALESCE(fDisclaimer.Description, dfDisclaimer.Description) Disclaimer,
  Main.Other
FROM Main
LEFT OUTER JOIN Fact fDescription
  ON fDescription.FactLinkID = Main.DescriptionID
   AND fDescription.ClientID = @clientID
   AND fDescription.LanguageID = @langID
   AND fDescription.StatusID = @statusID -- This actually needs to get the largest `StatusOrder`, not the `StatusID`.
LEFT OUTER JOIN Fact dfDescription
  ON dfDescription.FactLinkID = Main.DescriptionID
   AND dfDescription.ClientID = 1
   AND dfDescription.LanguageID = @langID
   AND dfDescription.StatusID = @statusID
... -- Same for Disclaimer
WHERE Main.ID = 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this the most performant or elegant way to solve this problem. But I finally thought of a way to do it. The problem with the solution below is that it can no longer be indexed. So, now to figure out how to do that without having to wrap it in a derived table.

```
SELECT
  x.ID,
  x.StatusOrder,
  x.LanguageID,
  x.ClientID,
  x.Other,
  MAX(x.Description),
  MAX(x.Disclaimer)
FROM (
  SELECT
    Main.ID,
    s.StatusOrder,
    f.LanguageID,
    f.ClientID,
    f.Description,
    NULL Disclaimer,
    Main.Other
  FROM Main
  JOIN Fact f
    ON f.FactID = Main.DescriptionID
  JOIN Status s ON s.StatusID = f.StatusID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Main.ID,
    s.StatusOrder,
    f.LanguageID,
    f.ClientID,
    NULL Description,
    f.Description Disclaimer,
    Main.Other
  FROM Main
  JOIN Fact f
    ON f.FactID = Main.DisclaimerID
  JOIN Status s ON s.StatusID = f.StatusID
) x
GROUP BY x.ID, x.StatusOrder, x.LanguageID, x.ClientID, x.Other
```