# Join and Group Tables without UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I asked [this question on how to join multiple tables in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982205/632495). I figured out an answer but it uses `UNION ALL` and nested selects. Is it possible to do without nested `SELECT`s and `UNION ALL`? I would like to index it. Not really sure if it is possible though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: USE PIVOT Instead https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, In the examples it shows nested `select` statements. Which means that the table view wouldn't be indexable still.

Comment: @Jon49 are you looking for this type query http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738005/4426282

Comment: @Lioness, It doesn't look like SQL Server supports `natural joins` but I'll see if I can implement it without it. Looks like a promising direction.